Protecting secrets in memory dumps
I have an embeded application that in case of asserts, creates (memory) dumps for analysis (also by 3rd party). The problem is that this application deals with secrets (keys, passwords) thay should be secret (esp. for me when I get a dump from a client).
The problem is the stack - it is included in the dump, so secrets will leak.
The only solution I've found so far is to move those parameters to globals that are declared in special memory region (declared in linker) that is out od the scope in the dump. Maybe there is a better way?
Environment for this is raw hardware embeded multicore system (no real OS). Assert may happen in another hardware thread. We are already limiting how long secret stays in memory to only neccessary time (by zeroing it with memset_s which is safe and will not be optimized out).

What about the memory where the clients store their credentials? Is that excluded from your dumps as well? In yes, could you work with pointers to the credentials instead of storing the credentials themselves in your local variables?

Does your application need to keep the sensitive information around all the time, or can it erase it ASAP?

Even if you move the stored values to be global variables, they're still going to be used by the program. They can end up in registers and on the stack whenever you manipulate them. A dump from a program should generally be considered as sensitive as the data manipulated by that program.

There are some invasive mitigating steps that could be taken (only manipulating the sensitive data in leaf functions then scrubbing the memory where stack was), but that would be tricky to do and doesn't really guarantee anything. If the asserts are never where secure data is manipulated, then I'd consider keeping all secure data in another thread/process (depending on how these asserts/dumps work), all in memory that isn't accessible to the asserting thread. If asserts can happen close to where secure data is handled, that doesn't work and I don't myself see a good solution.

Which platform? AFAIK on Windows there is a way to have piece of memory which will not be part of dump. Long time ago I had own implementation of string which was using custom allocator to keep secrets in this part of memory.

If the part that needs to see the secrets is relatively small (maybe just a couple of DB connection strings/API keys?), it might be possible to simply run those bits in a separate process and exchange non-sensitive info via IPC.

I think Ian's remark goes a long way, and is prudent advice anyway: If all asserts are your own you can make sure to scrub the sensitive information before asserting. Admittedly, that will complicate the code (e.g. instead of simply assert(critical condition); it would be  if(!critical_condition) { memset(secret, 0, sizeof(secret)); assert(critical_condition); }).

Do note that just because a variable has been overwritten, that doesn't mean that all traces of it are gone. A copy could still be held in a register, or have been copied to the stack and not yet been overwritten by other data. It's an extra security measure, but offers no guarantees, especially in a case like this.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica memset() cannot be used to scrub sensitive information, use memset_explicit() or similar function instead. Details are as described on Notes of this page.

@kakkoko Ah, thanks. makes sense.

@Gerhardh because of need to use 3rd party libraries with fixed APIs we're unable to just use pointers.

@ThomasJager unfortunately asserts can (but should not of course) happen all over the place. (fortunately) registers are not part of the dumps

@MarekR raw hardware embeded (no real OS)

@Cubic I do not have real OS here to work with

@Peter-ReinstateMonica assert can happen in another hardware thread :(

@kakkoko we use memset_s where neccesary

@AdamKłobukowski Registers can always be spilled to the stack, especially if the compiler thinks that they should be preserved around calls. If the assert must be able to happen in the same memory space that handles sensitive data, and the data must be handled in normal CPU registers (as opposed to dedicated crypto hardware), I don't see how you can easily be completely sure that no data will leak if the stack, (or the heap if you use std::string, etc.) is in the dump. If your software manipulates some data, it could end up on the stack, even if it's not explicit in your source code.

@AdamKłobukowski any vital information should be added to question by [edit] not as a comment, so other user don't have to scan comets, to provide an answer. Please add to question details about hardware, since you wrote about some emended system. Note this mean quite narrow specialization, so not many users can help. Possibly add tag specific for that platform.

@MarekR TY. Fixed.

@AdamKłobukowski again provide detail about platform and use tags associated with this platform to attract people who know that platform ("embeded multicore system" is meaningless). With current details/tags your question is doomed to be ignored.

@MarekR unfortunately I'm not at liberty to do so :(
